# Время доступа к полям Bitfield

Tags: c++

> 7.25 Bitfields
>
> Bitfields may be useful for making data more compact.
>   **Accessing a member of a bitfield is less efficient than accessing a**
>   **member of a structure**. The extra time may be justified in case of
>   large arrays if it can save cache space or make files smaller.

Почему доступ к Bitfield медленнее чем к структуре?

[Источник](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Битовые поля - конструкция уровня языка. Типичный процессор не имеет команд для прямой работы с битовыми полями. Поэтому компилятору придется выполнять набор битовых операций над содержащим битовое поле словом памяти для того, чтобы прочитать или записать значение этого битового поля. Вот на это и тратится дополнительное время.

Вот, например, как выглядит простое присваивание значения битовому полю

```
struct S
{
  unsigned int a : 5, b : 10, c : 5;
};
...
struct S s;
s.b = rand();
```

Получаем

```
//call    rand

and     eax, 1023
sal     eax, 5
mov     edx, eax
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
and     eax, -32737
or      eax, edx
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], eax
```

Вся эта последовательность команд - это запихивание результата `rand` в битовое поле.

Answer (score 2):

Да потому что каждое обращение должно еще и выделить из байта(ов) нужные биты, а при записи - соответственно их изменить и записать.

Все это требует процессорного времени - просто за вас это "пишет" компилятор...